# Не могу выбрать random фразу из списка для своего бота телеграм

Tags: python-3.x, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

Нужно чтобы бот выбирал каждый раз случайную фразу из списка. Я пытался использовать random.choice, он действительно выбирает случайную фразу, но лишь только один раз. Во время работы бота он все время повторяет только одну выбраную фразу. Я же хочу чтобы при получении сообщения бот реагировал на словои выбирал каждый раз случайную фразу из списка. Надеюсь понятно обьяснил, вот полный код бота, чтобы было понятнее:

```
import telebot
import config
import random
import numpy

bot = telebot.TeleBot(config.token)

list = (['Осуждаю','Не одобряю','Максимальное осуждение' 'Бан'])
pid = random.choice(list)
pid1 = numpy.random.choice(list,replace=False)

@bot.message_handler(regexp='Слива|груша|яблоко|банан|орех')
def handle_message(message):
    bot.reply_to(message, pid)
bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы в самом начале программы вызвали `random.choice`, т.е. всего один раз выбрали случайную фразу и удивляетесь, что эта фраза повторяется.

Быть может вы имели ввиду вот это? А именно - каждый раз, при вызове обработчика выбирать случайную фразу.

```
@bot.message_handler(regexp='Слива|груша|яблоко|банан|орех')
def handle_message(message):
    pid = random.choice(list)
    bot.reply_to(message, pid)
```

И `list`, это имя встроенного типа, никогда так не называйте свои объекты. Используйте, условный, `answers_list`. А что значит имя `pid` - известно только вам.

Comment: Спасибо, все оказалось настолько просто)